# How to store Bangla font in SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In which way i can store bangla language in SQLite database in Android.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do? If you want to implement localization, then you should not store it in the SQLite database, you should make use of string xml resources file. Kindly provide more information.

Comment: @AlokGupta I want to build a quiz app in bangla. That's why i want to store quiz question and answer in sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like this

```
public boolean insert() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put("question", "তুমি কেমন আছ?");

  db.insert("questions", null, contentValues);
  return true;
}
```

I am just trying to mention that we can put whatever we want to store inside quotation marks and it will store it.

Comment: It need't to change any collation?

Comment: I believe it will work without anything extra, please try and let me know, we can discuss more if required